# Retrofit with OKHTTP3 certification pinning

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit, okhttp, certificate-pinning

I am using Retrofit 1.9 with OKHTTP3 client and I am trying to add certification pinning. Below is the relevant code:

```
String hostname = "xxxxxx.xx";

CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add(hostname, "sha1/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=")
    .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
     .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
     .build();

return new RestAdapter.Builder()
     .setRequestInterceptor(request -> {
         request.addHeader("CONTENT-TYPE", "application/json");
     })
     .setEndpoint("https://xxxxxxxxxxxx").
     .setClient(new Ok3Client(client))
     .build();
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working. I don't have the

```
"javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate pinning failure!"
```

exception and even my host or SHA is incorrect. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: @lensniak could you tell me how you got pins ("sha1/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=")

Comment: I got the certificate (sha1) from endpoint (serwer) to which I send queries.

Comment: But they (server) giving only certificate

Comment: You can read Certificate Fingerprints (sha1, sha256...) from certificate. Tool:  https://www.samltool.com/fingerprint.php or https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/identity-protection-support/index?page=content&id=SO28771&actp=RSS&viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple things to check, since you've redacted the parts were mistakes are common, I can't tell for certain if these are you issue, but both mistakes will cause no pinning with no logs.

1) For `hostname` in your `CertificatePinner`, make sure it is just the host name, like "www.example.com", and not a url "https://www.example.com".
2) For `.setEndpoint("xxxxxxxxxxxx")`, make sure you endpoint is `https`, there are no certs checked on `http` so no logs.